# HTML5 canvas for loop wont draw the first object in array

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So basically. I'm trying to loop through each letter in a text (in this case the text is "marius"). Now, the problem is that the first letter is never drawn. If the text is "marius", it draws "arius". I've tried what I can think of, but I can't find the error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Don't worry about anything else. The code is not done, but this problem if eating my brains out. Thanks in advance. :)

```js
WebFont.load({

  google: {
    families: ['Audiowide']
  },

  active: function() {

    // Just the requestAnimationFrame
    // for different types of browsers
    const requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

    // Canvas
    const c = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    const cWidth = c.width = window.innerWidth;
    const cHeight = c.height = window.innerHeight;

    // Framerate settings
    // Better not touch theese if you
    // do not know what you are doing
    let now, delta;
    let fps = (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? 29 : 60;
    let then = Date.now();
    const interval = 1000 / fps;



    /*-------------------------------------------------------
         PREPARATION BELOW
    -------------------------------------------------------*/

    var text = 'marius';
    var letters = [];
    var lettersCount;
    const config = {
      'background': '#222',
      'letterSize': '72px',
      'letterFont': 'Audiowide',
      'letterSpacing': 50,
      'amp': 60,
      'yOffset': cHeight / 2
    };

    for (let i = 0, lettersCount = text.length; i < lettersCount; i++) {
      letters.push(new Letter(text[i]));
    }

    for (let i = 0, len = letters.length; i < len; i++) {
      var addThisToo = (i == 0) ? 0 : letters[i - 1].letterOffset;
      var letterWidth = getTextWidth(letters[i].letter, config.letterSize + ' ' + config.letterFont);
      letters[i].letterOffset = letterWidth + addThisToo;
    }

    /*-------------------------------------------------------
         END PREPARATION
    -------------------------------------------------------*/



    /**
     * draw()
     * The draw function, where everything is happening
     * @return null
     */
    function draw() {

      looper();
      if (delta > interval) {

        // Calculate then
        then = now - (delta % interval);

        // All your own stuff here
        drawBackground();
        drawLetters();

      }

    }

    /**
     * drawLetters()
     * Draw the letters from letters Array
     * Sinusoidal wave!
     */
    function drawLetters() {

      for (let i = 0, len = letters.length; i < len; i++) {

        // Prepare X and Y of the letter
        let letterOffset = (i > 0) ? letters[i - 1].letterOffset : letters[i].letterOffset;
        let x = letters[i].xPos + letterOffset;
        let y = config.yOffset + (sin(letters[i].xPos / 45 + i) * config.amp);

        // Create gradient color
        var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, cWidth, 0);
        gradient.addColorStop('0', '#ff6666');
        gradient.addColorStop('0.5', '#66ff66');
        gradient.addColorStop('1', '#6666ff');

        // Draw and fill the letter
        ctx.font = config.letterSize + ' ' + config.letterFont;
        ctx.fillText(letters[i].letter, x, y);
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

        // Update letter X and Y position
        letters[i].yPos += 0.05 * i;
        letters[i].xPos -= letters[i].xVel;


      }

    }

    /**
     * letter(letter)
     * Letter object
     * @return nul
     */
    function Letter(letter) {

      this.letter = letter;
      this.xPos = cWidth;
      this.yPos = 0;
      this.xVel = 2;
      this.yVel = 0;
      this.letterOffset = 0;

    }

    /**
     * Looper()
     * Looper function, do not touch!
     * @return null
     */
    function looper() {
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      now = Date.now();
      delta = now - then;
    }

    /**
     * drawBackground()
     * Draws the background
     * @return null
     */
    function drawBackground() {
      ctx.fillStyle = config.background;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    }

    /**
     * randInt(min, max)
     * Returns random integer between min - max
     * @param integer min
     * @param integer max
     * @return integer
     */
    function randInt(min, max) {
      max = max === undefined ? min - (min = 0) : max;
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }

    /**
     * sin(x)
     * Sinus of X
     * @return float
     */
    function sin(x) {
      return Math.sin(x);
    }

    /**
     * getTextWidth(text, font)
     * Return the width of the text
     * @return integer
     */
    function getTextWidth(text, font) {
      ctx.font = font;
      var metrics = ctx.measureText(text);
      return Math.round(metrics.width);
    }

    /**
     * EventListener - Click
     */
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      let x, y;

      if (e.offsetX) {
        x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;
      } else if (e.layerX) {
        x = e.layerX;
        y = e.layerY;
      }

    });

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.18/webfont.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your implementation is that you set the `ctx.fillStyle` after you do the `fillText` call. This means that you only set the `fillStyle` of the second letter and as the default `fillStyle` is black the first will not be visible. If you switch the two lines it will work.

Then you have a second mistake which is that the first and the second letter are at the same `x` position. I changed the preparation method and the draw method to make the letter spacing work properly.

```js
WebFont.load({

  google: {
    families: ['Audiowide']
  },

  active: function() {

    // Just the requestAnimationFrame
    // for different types of browsers
    const requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

    // Canvas
    const c = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    const cWidth = c.width = window.innerWidth;
    const cHeight = c.height = window.innerHeight;

    // Framerate settings
    // Better not touch theese if you
    // do not know what you are doing
    let now, delta;
    let fps = (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? 29 : 60;
    let then = Date.now();
    const interval = 1000 / fps;



    /*-------------------------------------------------------
         PREPARATION BELOW
    -------------------------------------------------------*/

    var text = 'marius';
    var letters = [];
    var lettersCount;
    const config = {
      'background': '#222',
      'letterSize': '72px',
      'letterFont': 'Audiowide',
      'letterSpacing': 50,
      'amp': 60,
      'yOffset': cHeight / 2
    };

    for (let i = 0, lettersCount = text.length; i < lettersCount; i++) {
      letters.push(new Letter(text[i]));
    }

    for (let i = 1, len = letters.length; i < len; i++) {
      var addThisToo = letters[i - 1].letterOffset;
      var letterWidth = getTextWidth(letters[i - 1].letter, config.letterSize + ' ' + config.letterFont);
      letters[i].letterOffset = letterWidth + addThisToo + config['letterSpacing'];
    }

    /*-------------------------------------------------------
         END PREPARATION
    -------------------------------------------------------*/



    /**
     * draw()
     * The draw function, where everything is happening
     * @return null
     */
    function draw() {

      looper();
      if (delta > interval) {

        // Calculate then
        then = now - (delta % interval);

        // All your own stuff here
        drawBackground();
        drawLetters();

      }

    }

    /**
     * drawLetters()
     * Draw the letters from letters Array
     * Sinusoidal wave!
     */
    function drawLetters() {

      for (let i = 0, len = letters.length; i < len; i++) {

        // Prepare X and Y of the letter
        let letterOffset = letters[i].letterOffset;
        let x = letters[i].xPos + letterOffset;
        let y = config.yOffset + (sin(letters[i].xPos / 45 + i) * config.amp);

        // Create gradient color
        var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, cWidth, 0);
        gradient.addColorStop('0', '#ff6666');
        gradient.addColorStop('0.5', '#66ff66');
        gradient.addColorStop('1', '#6666ff');

        // Draw and fill the letter
        ctx.font = config.letterSize + ' ' + config.letterFont;
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctx.fillText(letters[i].letter, x, y);

        // Update letter X and Y position
        letters[i].yPos += 0.05 * i;
        letters[i].xPos -= letters[i].xVel;


      }

    }

    /**
     * letter(letter)
     * Letter object
     * @return nul
     */
    function Letter(letter) {

      this.letter = letter;
      this.xPos = cWidth;
      this.yPos = 0;
      this.xVel = 2;
      this.yVel = 0;
      this.letterOffset = 0;

    }

    /**
     * Looper()
     * Looper function, do not touch!
     * @return null
     */
    function looper() {
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      now = Date.now();
      delta = now - then;
    }

    /**
     * drawBackground()
     * Draws the background
     * @return null
     */
    function drawBackground() {
      ctx.fillStyle = config.background;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    }

    /**
     * randInt(min, max)
     * Returns random integer between min - max
     * @param integer min
     * @param integer max
     * @return integer
     */
    function randInt(min, max) {
      max = max === undefined ? min - (min = 0) : max;
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }

    /**
     * sin(x)
     * Sinus of X
     * @return float
     */
    function sin(x) {
      return Math.sin(x);
    }

    /**
     * getTextWidth(text, font)
     * Return the width of the text
     * @return integer
     */
    function getTextWidth(text, font) {
      ctx.font = font;
      var metrics = ctx.measureText(text);
      return Math.round(metrics.width);
    }

    /**
     * EventListener - Click
     */
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      let x, y;

      if (e.offsetX) {
        x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;
      } else if (e.layerX) {
        x = e.layerX;
        y = e.layerY;
      }

    });

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.18/webfont.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ohh, i see. Thanks! Wasn't the biggest error in my life, but certainly did not catch it. Thanks!

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball no problem. I also just corrected the letter spacing

Comment: I just spent an hour trying to understand what I was doing wrong, you just saved me from giving up